# Last two digits of decimal number with a mask?

Tags: python, bitmap, binary, bit, bit-shift

To get the last N digits of a decimal number I usually convert it to a string. For example, for two digits:

```
n = 129387
int((str(n)[-2:]))
# 87
```

With binary its relatively straightforward to do this with a mask, such as:

```
n = 0b00101001
'{:02b}'.format(0b00101001& 0b11)
# '01'
# -- or -- 
'{:02b}'.format(0b00101001& 0x3)
# '01'
```

Is it possible to apply a mask to a deicimal number to get the last two digits, `87` in the above example?

Comment: I think you are referring to the mod operator, e.g. `129387%100 = 87`? The general case is `base**n` where `n` is the number of digits in the base, e.g. binary case `format(0b00101001 % 2**2, '02b')`

Comment: Unless you convert to string, you **don't have** a "decimal number".

Comment: @AChampion yes exactly -- that was much easier than I though it would be!

Comment: @superbrain yes that was a typo

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 Ha! I hadn't even noticed that typo :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referring to the mod operator, e.g.:

```
In []:
129387 % 100  # 10**2

Out[]:
87
```

The general case is `base**n` where `n` is the number of digits in the `base`, e.g. binary case:

```
In []:
format(0b00101001 % 2**2, '02b')

Out[]:
'01'

In []:
format(0b00101001 % 2**4, '02b')

Out[]:
'1001'
```